# Lorentz transformations of energy and relativistic 3-momentum

Tags: matrices, transformation, special-relativity

My question is how do energy and the relativistic 3-momentum change under a Lorentz transformation?
I know that the 4-momentum transforms as $P' = \Lambda P$ where $\Lambda$ is a $4\times 4$ Lorentz transformation matrix, and I thought that using this should tell me how the energy and momentum transform as the 4-momentum encapsulates both of these quantities, but I am unsure on how to proceed with this as there are many $4\times 4$ Lorentz transformation matrices, and doing the algebra with the 'boost along $x$-axis matrix' didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Comment: Writing in index notation you have $p^\mu\to \Lambda^\mu_\nu p^\nu$, just as you would for any other four-vector. So for instance the energy will transform as $p^0\to \Lambda^0_\nu p^\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match the dimensions of momentum, $p^0$ has to be defined as $p^0 = E/c$ where $E$ is the relativistic energy (=rest + kinetic).  Taking a boost in the $x$ direction with speed $v$, let $\beta = v/c$ and $\gamma = (1-\beta^2)^{-1/2}$.  Then
\begin{align}
\frac{E'}{c} &= \gamma (\frac{E}{c} - \beta p^1)\\
p^1{'} &= \gamma(p^1-\beta\frac{E}{c})\\
p^2{'} &= p^2\\
p^3{'} &= p^3
\end{align}

The Lorentz group has 4 components, with the identity component $SO^+(1,3)$ called the proper orthochronous Lorentz group.  It is generated by 6 one-parameter subgroups, each generated by an infinitesimal generator of the Lie algebra.  Three of these are Euclidean rotations in the $xy, yz, zx$ planes.  The other three are boosts in the hyperbolic planes $tx, ty, tz$.  (notice that $\gamma = \cosh \varphi$, $\beta = \tanh \varphi$ and $\gamma \beta = \sinh \varphi$ for some $\varphi$ called the rapidity.)

A convenient alternative view is given as follows.  Let $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the group of $2$ by $2$ matrices with determinant $1$.  Now represent a vector $(ct, x, y, z)$ in Minkowski space as
$$X =
\begin{pmatrix}
ct + z & x - iy\\
x + iy & ct - z
\end{pmatrix}$$

(this is the space of all Hermitian $2$ by $2$ complex matrices.)
Notice that $\det(X)$ is the Lorentz metric.  Now consider the action of $A$ on $X$ given by
$$X \mapsto A X A^*$$
Since $\det(A) = 1$ we have $\det(AXA^*) = \det(X)$ so this preserves the Lorentz metric.  The image of this map from $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ to the Lorentz group is $SO^+(1,3)$, and the map is a double cover (note that $-A$ acts the same as $A$.)  This map is the universal cover of $SO^+(1,3)$ which has fundamental group $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ while $SL_2(\Bbb{C})$ is simply connected.

If you want $A$ to act on a momentum 4-vector then take
$$P =
\begin{pmatrix}
E/c + p^3 & p^1 - ip^2\\
p^1 + ip^2 & E/c - p^3
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the action $P\mapsto A P A^*$.

Answer (score 0):

The equations that I used when I learned the theory of relativity more than 30 years ago were:
$$
x = \gamma(x'+t'v), \quad y=y', \quad z=z', \quad t=\gamma(t'+x'v/c^2)
$$
for the coordinates. Here the primed system is moving with speed $v$ in the positive $x$ direction. As usual, $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}.$

For energy and momentum we then have
$$
p_x = \gamma(p_x'+E'v/c^2), \quad p_y=p_y', \quad p_z=p_z',\quad E=\gamma(E'+p_x'v).
$$